# Arbitrary functions

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to teach myself programming and am currently working my way through 'A Primer on Scientific Programming with Python' by Hans Petter Langtangen.
Right now I'm on Exercise 3.20. Unfortunately I don't have any solutions to the problems..

I know I can use an arbitrary (mathematical) function f in the definition of a method:

```
def diff(f,x,h=0.001):  
    return (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2*h
```

And when I call it i can use whatever function I wish:

```
print diff(math.exp,0)
print diff(math.cos,2*math.pi)
```

So here's my question: 
Is There a way to accomodate more complex functions in this way?
Say for example I would like to approximate the derivative of a function like
x(t) = e^(-(t-4)^2)
like I did above for cos(x) and e^(x).

Edit: maybe I should be more clear. I'm not specifically trying to differentiate this one function e^(-(t-4)^2) but would like to define a method that takes ANY function of x as an argument and approximates a derivative at point x.
I was impressed when I learned that you could do it for simple functions like cos(x), sin(x) and exp(x) at all. So I thought if that works there must be a way to make it more general..

Comment: ... simply define that function: `def f(t): return math.exp(-(t-4)**2)` and pass `f` to `diff`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just define it first:

```
def x(t):
    return math.exp(-(t-4)**2)

print diff(x, 0)
```

Instead of using `def`, it's often possible to use `lambda` if the function consists of a single expression that is returned:

```
print diff(lambda t: math.exp(-(t-4)**2), 0)
```

Comment: Yeah I know that. But what I would like is to define this derivative approximation once and then be able to use it on arbitrary functions. So for example I would like to call it with e^(-(t-4)^2) and then with e^(-(t-5)^3) or something..

Comment: That's what the `def diff(...)` does, isn't it? You do that once, and from then on you can use the `diff` function on arbitrary functions. I must be missing your problem.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't read your answer carefully enough. Yeah I guess that should work. Thanks

Comment: Using the lambda notation in my answer, `diff(lambda x: math.exp(x**2 + 1), x)`

Answer (score 0):

sure:

```
def x(t):
    return diff(math.exp(-(t-4)**2))
```